# Wie sagt man "Phew" auf Deutsch?

Tags: onomatopoeia

Wenn ich nach einer Übersetzung der englischen Onomatopöie "Phew" suche, finde ich nur "puh", aber im Englischen würde "puh" etwas ganz anderes bedeuten.

Also, was wäre die deutsche Onomatopöie für dieses Emoticon:

[image: Phew_small]

Comment: Ich verstehe den Grund für die Frage nicht ganz. Wenn ich nach einer deutschen Übersetzung für "red" suche, finde ich "rot", aber im Englischen bedeutet "rot" etwas anderes – ja, und?

Comment: @DonHolgo Ich wurde von Google verwirrt und in ein paar Jahren wird diese Frage Google hit # 1 sein!  **0:-)**

Comment: As all tags are in English, shouldn't it be "Onomatopoeia"?

Comment: @Iris: added English tag as well. do you have enough rep here to create a synonym?

Comment: @Fabby, I don't know how to create a synonym.

Comment: @Iris No worries: contacted a mod.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The equivalent is what you found out by yourself. It is indeed

> Puh!

Answer (score 15):

Ich meine, etwas älter und somit "literarischer" als "Puh" ist

> Uff!

Zur Verifizierung der These böte es sich an, alte Mickymaushefte durchzublättern aus verschiedenen Jahrgängen, um zu schauen, wie sich die onomatopoetische Gestaltung von Lautäußerungen der Erleichterung über die Jahre entwickelt. Sobald ich wieder Zugriff zu diesem Textkorpus habe, mache ich einmal Stichproben.

Am Rande sei - kontrastiv differenzierend - hinzubemerkt, dass sich in den Dialogen bei Karl May (Sprachkultur der 1860er Jahre) sehr häufig

> Pah!

findet, dies aber **als Laut der Verachtung oder Geringschätzung**. Dieses "Pah!" hat sich aus dem Alltags- und Literatursprachgebrauch seither verflüchtigt. Allenfalls im heute geläufigen, milderen

> Pff!

kann man noch einen Reflex des groben "Pah!" aus der Zeit des deutschen Realismus erkennen.

Noch weniger aggressiv als "Pff!" wäre das um einen Schwa-Laut ergänzte

> Pfü!

bei dem ich - jedenfalls - neben der missachtenden Ablehnung auch eine diese Haltung relativierende Selbstironie mithöre.

Comment: Ich wohne nur zeit wenige Zeit in Deutschland, sondern habe ich keine Deutsche Mickymaushefte, aber sowieso **+1  ;-)**

Comment: +1, aber: Vielleicht hat Karl May mich geprägt, aber ich empfinde »pah« als Ausruf der Verachtung oder Geringschätzung nicht als veraltet. Vermutlich würde ich es aber auch anders ausdrücken. Eine spontane Gefühlsäußerung lässt sich so schwer authentisch simulieren.

Comment: @Philipp  Ja... ich schrieb "veraltet", weil ich es außerhalb der Karl-May-Welt noch nicht angetroffen habe, insbesondere nicht in Post-May-Zeiten. Das kann aber auch an meiner beschränkten Weltkenntnis (oder Literaturkenntnis) liegen.

Comment: Ächz! Da erwarte ich ein *(h)ui*, aber pah! Stehen da zwar Lautäußerungen mit *P*, aber viel zu wenig mit dem Buchstaben *A*, wie *Äeh* (weiß gar nicht, wie das in all seinen Varianten zu verschriftlichen wäre.).

Comment: @LangLangC  Umpf. Der Fragesteller wollte doch ein Äquivalent für "Phew".

Comment: Genau. Funktionsäquivalent, nicht Buchstabenäquivalent oder nur -ähnlich. Daher ist *pah* viel weniger passend als *ächz* oder *hui*. Beachte die Erleichterung nach Schweissabsonderung durch Aufregung/Stress im Bild. Meine ich jedenfalls. Das ebenfalls gelistete "Puh" halte ich für literarisch und im Alltag lautlich für nichtexistent. (Jedenfalls nicht spontan) Your call.

Comment: Huch. Muss mich da selbst korrigieren und ergänzen. Kurze unwissenschaftliche Umfrage gemacht: Pff (alle Varianten zusammen: frikative Sammlung ohne Vokale) wurde tatsächlich etwas häufiger genannt als puh und dann (b)oah. Mit *ächz* hat mich Frau Fuchs wohl fehlgeprägt mit ihrer Hochliteratur…

Comment: Ts-ts-ts. Ich hatte "Puh" auch gar nicht als gute Alternative propagiert. Grummel. Und "Pah" kam nur vor, damit es nach 140 Jahren mal wieder jemand aktiv verwendet. Nörgel. "Ächz" ist nach meiner Kenntnis der Fuchs'schen Ausdrucksformen eher im Fällen aktuell empfundender schwerer Lasten gängig, nicht jedoch zur Expression der Erleichterung über deren Loswerden. Hugh, ich habe gesprochen.

Comment: Eigentlich ist dieser Ausruf/-druck der Erleichterung ja vor allem ein akustisches Phänomen: ein "p" gefolgt von hörbarem Ausatmen. Puh! ist diejenige Schreibweise, die dem an nächsten kommt. --- @ Christian Geiselmann: Bei Karl May (Wildwest-Version) und "Ausdruck der Verachtung" habe ich da eher "Pshaw"  in Erinnerung (oder Pschaw? - Bin mir bei der Schreibweise gerade nicht sicher, sind der Jahrzehnte doch ein paar zuviele)